# How do I farm Human Effigies?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 1 there were several enemies that would commonly drop Humanity that were within a reasonable farming time. There are more than a few enemies in Dark Souls 2 that drop Effigies as well (essentially the same item). But in Dark Souls 2 enemies can only be killed 12 times before they disappear, meaning you only have 12 chances (sans [Bonfire Ascetic](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Bonfire_Ascetic)) to kill anything and hope it drops something. So, while you might get a few it isn't nearly as much as you had access to in Dark Souls 1. This means you can cause your character to be permanently debilitated and get stuck behind a boss that you can't quite beat on your own.

So how can I farm (or buy) Effigy's or restore my humanity consistently?

Comment: You need to select Wilson.. oh wait...

Comment: You can get 9 right at start of the game. Kill the old women in red that is sitting down; she drops 6 and the maid gives 3 more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Human Effigies can be found from Starting Gift, Static Locations (corpses), Merchants (All merchants have limited supply), and NPC's (both given and dropped when killed).

The term 'farm' usually implies an unlimited resource, as you pointed out.  As of the latest patch, the Company of Champions covenant allows infinite respawn.

These are enemies that drop Effigies:

- Attack Dogs.
- Skeletons [not in Undead Purgatory]
- Turtle Knights.
- Sentinel (Sword/Shield) and Sentinel (Great Sword)

Always remember you can farm 6 effigies off of the Old Firekeepers and 3 alone off Housekeeper Milibeth in Things Betwixt.

> After unlocking the Shrine of Winter, it is possible to farm Smooth and Silky Stones. While not directly farming Effigies, these have a high conversion rate to Effigies at Dyna & Tillo (Drop trade crow), although this is random.

There is however a way to restore humanity consistently.

> In the Shrine of Amana, above the last bonfire, there is a Shrine with a praying Milfinito. After you have 'rescued' the two stray maidens (one outside the Demon of Song room, another behind the Embedded Door in Drangleic Castle) you can pray at this Shrine at any time to regain humanity. This is free of cost and can be done a limitless amount of times.

There is an easier way, although it seems so easy that it will be patched.

> This requires the Ring of Life Protection, which can be found at the No Man's Wharf. This ring prevents loss of your Humanity and souls on death, but breaks afterwards. This ring can be repaired for 3000 at the blacksmith giving a constant 3000 Souls per Human transfer rate. A +1 Ring of Life Protection (Also prevents petrification) can be purchased from Vengarl in the Shaded Woods.

Comment: I have read that the shrine only works if you have no Effigies in your inventory. Do you know if this is true?

Comment: AFIK you have to be both Hollow, and have no Effigies in your inventory *and* in your box.

Comment: I have not tried 'Leaving' Effigies on the ground before trying, that was a tactic that worked often in these scenarios in DSI.

Comment: Leaving effigies doesn't work sadly.

Comment: In regards to Skeletons, a Bonfire Ascetic will also respawn the Skeleton underneath the mansion in Majula. Each respawn adds an additional skeleton (for a max of 8). Each skeleton drops an effigy. Do note that this also increases the difficulty of the pigs. Also, if you ever plan on killing Licia, do it as soon as possible before she's grown more powerful than you could ever imagine.

Answer (score 2):

The area by the second blacksmith has dogs that are 3 second farms and if you can use a bonfire ascentic thing then they should be easy enough, it's a slow process though so rusted coins might be a helpful option

Comment: The Bonfire Ascetic raises the difficulty of the whole area permanently though so while it gives your more chances it can still hinder a player having trouble with an area.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tip

There are so much ways of getting humanity in DS2 but this by far the best and easiest way.
You know the rings that you can rarely find if you wear it, it will allow you to not loose human form or souls upon death but the downside is it will break after being used...well all you need to do is go to the blacksmith in Majula and repair it for around 3000 souls so for a little price you can have **unlimited** humanity  not to mention not having to worry about loosing all your souls :).

I can't remember the rings name but you can find one in No-man's Wharf (Pirate place), it can also be found on enemies you kill but it is very rare.

*Might get patched because it's getting exploited and makes the game so easy*

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a bit of co-op then you could help someone kill a boss. That restores you to human.

Comment: Not all the time. It seems to happen less and less frequently the more you do it.

Comment: Been fixed in patch 1.03: Helping someone slightly reverses Hollowing. If you're back at max HP it'll turn you human again. Not random anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way of Farming Human effigies

In this video he is showing how to farm human effigies. When you get to the first Forest of Fallen Giants bonfire, burn a bonfire ascetix and collect all of the loot on the map.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include the content of what's happening in the video in case it is removed in the future?